# Is Python 3.x dictionary lint type check (typing) set at instantiation

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, lint, typing

I have a configuration dictionary which I load with values in a hierarchy of dunder init calls, each call instantiates part of the configuration. Trying to add typing to this I have received a strange behavior (or maybe I'm doing something wrong). The behavior I'm getting is consistent with the dictionary giving out types that were only inserted to it in its first declaration, updating extending and adding keys does not seem to change the types a dictionary declares as possible when accessing it, this is a simple code I wrote to illustrate the problem:

```
import re


def foo(a: int = 1, b: str = "b"):
    d = {"a": a}
    d.update({"b": b})
    print(re.findall(d["b"], "baba"))


foo()
```

The code of course works and outputs `['b', 'b']` (no pun intended) but my pycharm gives out two warnings:

1. on the update line: `Unexpected type(s):<br>(Dict[str, str])<br>Possible types:<br>(Mapping[str, int])<br>(Iterable[Tuple[str, int]])`
2. on the finditer line: `Expected type 'Union[bytes, str, __Regex]', got 'int' instead`

My questions are, is my analysis of the reason for this true (dict setting its typing on instantiation)? and is there a pythonic way to fix these warnings?

Comment: Updates to collection literals are supported since 2018.1 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-1182. What PyCharm version do you use?

Comment: 2017.3 :( , but thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> updating extending and adding keys does not seem to change the types a dictionary declares

This is by design. If you have some variable declared to be of type `Dict[str, int]`, you presumably want mypy to complain very loudly if you accidentally try running code like `var['foo'] = 'bar'`.

In this case, since you assigned `d` to a dict of string to ints, mypy assumes you meant for that type to be just `Dict[str, int]`.

If you want your code to type-check, you have several options:

1. Explicitly declare what types you expect your dictionary's values to be and use asserts or casts to confirm that the types of certain keys are what you expect them to be:

   ```
   def foo(a: int = 1, b: str = "b") -> None:
       d: Dict[str, Union[int, str]] = {"a": a}
       d.update({"b": b})

       # If you want to check your assumption at runtime
       b_regex = d["b"]
       assert isinstance(b_regex, str)
       print(re.findall(b_regex, "baba"))

       # If you don't want/don't need to check the type
       print(re.findall(cast(str, d["b"]), "baba"))
   ```
2. Give up on typing your dict statically and make the value be [the dynamic 'Any'](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dynamic_typing.html):

   ```
   def foo(a: int = 1, b: str = "b") -> None:
       d: Dict[str, Any] = {"a": a}
       d.update({"b": b})
       print(re.findall(d["b"], "baba"))
   ```
3. Use the [`TypedDict` mypy extension](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict) to indicate that the dict will only contain certain string keys, where each key has a corresponding value of some specific type.

   Note that this is currently a mypy-only extension, though there are plans to add it to PEP 484 as a full-fledged type in the near future. Once that happens, PyCharm is effectively obligated to understand TypedDict (though it's possible they've already gone ahead and added support early, not sure).

Comment: Since this is a configuration dictionary and I can't know what it contains, I think I'll go with 2